# JQuery: Populate HTML dropdown menu with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I know this questions been asked before, I've read other posts and couldn't get it to work.

I'm trying to populate a drop down menu with JSON data but I'm having some issues, the drop down appears on my html page but theres nothing in the drop down, not even the "Please Select". Below is my code, do you see any problems with it.

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropDown">
    </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/Dynamic?database=',
        dataType: 'Json',
        success: function (results) {
            var $el = $("#dropDown");
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value).text(value));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**JSON**

```
["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]
```

Comment: It's not an answer, but https://select2.github.io/ has a really easy implementation for this.

Comment: Have you checked the actual JSON response?

Comment: are you sure the request is actually successful?

Comment: Yes the response is correct, I've used this exact AJAX call before, except  now everything after "success" has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included jquery in your html `head` tag
Please also check your ajax is returning json data
I have make a fiddle and its working fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $el = $("#dropDown");
var results = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"];
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value).text(value));
            });
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o5ju4kja/

Comment: I've commented out my code and copied in yours, and I still get the same result, an empty drop down. I've included the JS script in the head, It should work, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: @JacksonSentzke but you can check in js fiddle ..its working

Comment: @JacksonSentzke check your console and let me know if you are getting any error

Comment: I know it's working in fiddle, but it's not working in my program.

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126811/discussion-between-jackson-sentzke-and-rajesh-patel).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var results = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"];

$(document).ready(function () {
            var $el = $("#dropDown");
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value).text(value));
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
    </select>
```

As you can see, the jquery code works. The problem must be in your ajax request not responding the desired json.

Comment: I don't believe it is, I've copied in your code and tried it but I got the same result, an empty drop down.

Comment: I've just copied your code straight into my html between a script tag and it worked. So it must be something wrong with how I'm including my JS file

Comment: I have, Yes it runs on here, but it doesn't run in my program.

Comment: Try debugging then.

Comment: Does it have to be a post request?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Try the network tab, there you should see the request and the answer

Comment: Got it working. Copied the code into a new javascript file and it worked straight away. Can't explain why it's suddenly working, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is working fine so please verify the following points:

- Verify that the request is working and you are receiving the correct answer.
- Confirm that jQuery is added - probably it's missing
- Verify that there is no error in console

```js
var results = ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"];

var $el = $("#dropDown");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$el.append($("<option></option>")
   .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
$.each(results, function (index, value) {
$el.append($("<option></option>")
   .attr("value", value).text(value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your **JSON** is not good encoding. Try to add a `contentType` format in your **Ajax** request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/Dynamic?database=',
        dataType: 'Json',
        contentType:"application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        cache:false,
        success: function (results) {
            var $el = $("#dropDown");
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value).text(value));
            });
        }
    });
});
```